# Purpose of object in argument of Lock statement

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

What is the purpose of object in Lock argument. Here is an example:

```
public class TestThreading  
{  
    private System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();  

    public void Process()  
    {  

        lock (lockThis)  
        {  
            // Access thread-sensitive resources.  
        }  
    }  

}
```

... does this 'lockThis' object pass anything into the Lock body. Why can't I use Lock statement without object in argument.

Comment: You need *some* variable that keeps track of which thread owns the lock and how often it has been entered.  The lock state.  System.Object is a seemingly inadequate type of object to do all of these things, but it is capable.   Many programmers have argued that the .NET Framework ought to have a dedicated type for this kind of variable to bring clarity.  You can make one: public class LockState : object {}.

Comment: Thanks. Would it make sense if I pass "Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId" into lock statement instead.

Comment: That would be disastrous.  You'd better study this or threading is going to eat you alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object passed to the lock statement can be thought of as an identifier for the lock. For any object, only a single thread can obtain an exclusive lock on that object at any given time. By allowing an object to be passed to the lock statement, you can use different objects for different areas of critical code.

The [`Monitor.Enter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter?view=netframework-4.7) documentation provides a better description of the use of the object than does the `lock` statement documentation.